# How to upload existing ms sql databse in web server?

Tags: asp.net, webserver

I have one web site and I want to upload it on server and i also want to upload the ms sql database with that web pages. Please tell me how to upload it on web server....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather generic question because there could be a lot of different problems and differences, but generally, you would take a backup of your server first. Here is some general information on that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx

Then log into your hosting provider, create a database using their tools, and restore your database backup to that new hosted database.

Next you would change where your database config in your files is pointing to the new database, then use an ftp client like Filezilla to ftp into your web server. The hosting provider should be able to give you the username and password. Upload the web pages / files to the public directory (usually /public or /htdocs or something along those lines).